# Run code block in a transaction in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I want to run the following code block in a transaction so that if any of the `sql statements` fail the entire transaction is aborted. If I run the following block as it is, does it run in a transaction or do I need to run it inside `BEGIN; ... COMMIT;`

```
DO $$
  DECLARE
    readonly_exists int;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO readonly_exists FROM information_schema.enabled_roles
    WHERE role_name = 'readonly';
  IF readonly_exists = 0 THEN
    <SQL STATEMENT 1>
    <SQL STATEMENT 2>
    <SQL STATEMENT 3>
  ELSE
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'readonly role already exists';
  END IF;
END$$;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any SQL statement always runs in a single transaction (the exception to this rule is `CALL`).

So your `DO` statement will run in a single transaction, and either all three SQL statements are successful, or all will be rolled back.

Comment: I saw at couple of places where `DO` statement was run inside `BEGIN` `COMMIT` . Is that a good practice to do ? I mean if `DO` statement is itself run in a transaction what's the point of running it inside `BEGIN` `COMMIT`

Comment: Since PostgreSQL uses autocommit mode, the `DO` statement will run in its own transaction by default. You start a transaction explicitly with `BEGIN` if you want other SQL statements to run in the same transaction as the `DO` statement.